# Powershell to export all user defined task from Task Sheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to export all the user defined task from Task Scheduler (and not system defined task). I am able to export all the data including system defined task using below command in PowerShell. Please advise if there is any way to pull only user defined task from task scheduler.

`schtasks /query /FO CSV /V > exportedtasks.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by a "system defined task", but I presume you want to see the same tasks as when selecting the `Task Scheduler Library` node in the `Task Scheduler` MMC.

If that's the case, you can call the [`Get-ScheduledTask`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask) cmdlet and filter on the `TaskPath` property like this:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\'
```

Comment: We have multiple inbuild task i.e. window update and some tasks are updated manually by users. I want the user defined manually updated task and not the system defined inbuild task.